# Winebottler prefix creation aborted

Tags: macos, wine

I've used Winebottler without problems to create an app bundle but now I can't create them anymore because I get a similar error for every attempt. I even tried creating a new user account and uninstalling Wine and Winebottler and deleting every trace of them from terminal but the problem remains. Any ideas?

```
###BOTTLING### Create .app...
###BOTTLING### Enabling CoreAudio, Colors, Antialiasing  and flat        menus...
wine: created the configuration directory    '/Users/Andrea/Desktop/Internet Explorer 7.app/Contents/Resources/wineprefix'
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface   {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface    {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub,   hres=0x80004002
err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyIpInterfaceChange (family 0, callback 0x6a07afa1,     context 0xa33c78, init_notify 0, handle 0x130f444): stub
fixme:iphlpapi:CancelMibChangeNotify2 (handle 0x0): stub
wine: configuration in '/Users/Andrea/Desktop/Internet Explorer     7.app/Contents/Resources/wineprefix' has been updated.
###BOTTLING### Sandboxing...
###BOTTLING### Installing Truetype Fonts...
###BOTTLING### Registering Truetype Fonts...
/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin
###BOTTLING### installing ie7
pathchk: illegal option -- P
usage: pathchk [-p] pathname...
curl: option --retry=3: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
curl: option --retry=3: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
### LOG ### Command 'sh  /private/tmp/winebottler_1478993302/nospace/winetricks.sh --no-isolate -q  ie7' returned status 1.

Using winetricks 20161107 - sha1sum:   b8b849448e41e2c2d33a3f0852eb3b91a35f105b with wine-1.8.0
Executing mkdir -p  /Users/Andrea/.cache/winetricks//tmp/winetricks.vWqXJIgq
Executing cd /Users/Andrea/.cache/winetricks//tmp/winetricks.vWqXJIgq
Task returned with status 1.
```

Comment: See https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/issues/695

Comment: I've read the comments on GitHub, I use Yosemite and the last successful prefix was created before OS X Security Update 2016-006, so I suspect that the update has broken winetricks.

Comment: I've got the same issue on macOS Sierra 10.12.1. I was previously able to install winetricks.
To fix the issue with WineBottler+Wine you should replace `~/Library/Application Support/Wine/winetricks` by `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks` (remove the use of `patchchk -P`). In suspect the Security Update to change something with the env PATH

Comment: It works beautifully